# Raku Native call gtk-clipboard-request-text?

Tags: raku

How would you call this library with Raku/Perl6's Native Call?

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-request-text

```
void
gtk_clipboard_request_text (GtkClipboard *clipboard,
                            GtkClipboardTextReceivedFunc callback,
                            gpointer user_data);
```

Many thanks,
-T

Edit: this question was HOW to call the function.  Not to troubleshoot a failed call.  No code was written at this point.

Comment: How did you try to call it and where did it fail?

Comment: JJ's question is appropriate for *all* questions on SO *and remains so even if **you** have the answer **you** want*. A key aspect of tech Q+As, doubly so for open source tech, triply for free-as-in-speech tech, quadruply here on SO, is it's not about you, it's about **us**. You may think that minimal information is better than providing too much. But, while providing useless or overly verbose info is indeed a negative, failing to say what you've researched and tried, and errors you've gotten and didn't understand, is far worse. Help us help you help us. Please consider updating your question.

Comment: JJ just misunderstood the question.  No code was not even written at this point.  I was asking HOW to call it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
use v6;
use NativeCall;

constant GdkAtom   := uint64;
constant GDK_NONE = 0x0;

sub gtk_init(Pointer $argc, Pointer $argv) is native('gtk-3') { * };
sub gdk_display_get_default() returns Pointer is native('gdk-3') { * };
sub gtk_clipboard_get_for_display(Pointer $display, GdkAtom $selection)
  returns Pointer is native('gtk-3') { * };
sub gtk_clipboard_request_text(
    Pointer $clipboard,
    &callback ( Pointer $clipbrd, Str $text, Pointer $data),
    Pointer $user_data) is native('gtk-3') { * };
sub gtk_main() is native('gtk-3') { * };
sub gtk_main_quit() is native('gtk-3') { * };


gtk_init(Pointer, Pointer);  # Pass NULL for arguments
my $display = gdk_display_get_default();

my $clipboard = gtk_clipboard_get_for_display( $display, GDK_NONE );
my $callback = my sub (Pointer $clipboard, Str $text, Pointer $data) {
    say "In callback: Text = $text";
    gtk_main_quit();
}
gtk_clipboard_request_text( $clipboard, &$callback, Pointer );
gtk_main();
```

This will print the text that is currently on the system's default clipboard.

Comment: Thank you!  `gtk-3` not `libgtk-3.so.0`?

Comment: Where is `Pointer` declared? NativeCall?

Comment: @Todd On my Ubuntu laptop I have installed a package `libgtk-3-dev`. It installs  the shared library at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so`. That why I used `gtk-3`

Comment: Yes :) the `Pointer` type is mentioned in [`documentation`](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#Basic_use_of_pointers)

Comment: Goodness that was a lot of work to put that example together.  Thank you!

In `gtk_clipboard_request_text( $clipboard, &$callback, Pointer );` I am not seeing what variable Pointer is assigned to.  I see it elsewhere such as `Pointer $data`

Comment: @Todd You are welcome! I have had some experience on using gtk+ from C and Perl, so I was able to figure it out by trial and error :)

Comment: When you pass a type object like `Pointer` without an associated variable, it will be converted to a `NULL` pointer according to the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#Basic_use_of_pointers)